# Windows batch script to find largest PDF file in subfolders and print with path in footer using Ghostscript and `pdftk`

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, ghostscript, pdftk

I have a large number of directories, and there are a lot of PDF files in them. I have to print the largest PDF file in each subdirectories with the path in the footer. I have searched a lot on the internet, and have found [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/171790/print-pdf-file-with-file-path-in-footer).

Based on it, I managed to create a new PDF manually with the path in the footer, but I can't really understand how to write a batch file in order to make it automatic. So I need to find the largest PDF in the subfolders, define actual path, and add path to footer, and then save them as a new file in the current subdirectory. Can you please help me with this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by *"largest PDF file"*? Largest in which terms? Biggest file size? Most pages? Largest page dimensions?

Comment: Yeah, biggest file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no one has answered; but I see much of the answer is in the [superuser article you cited](https://superuser.com/questions/171790/print-pdf-file-with-file-path-in-footer). They show  (in one of the answers) a complete batch file for adding the pdf footer.

All you need now is to find the largest file. Elsewhere on stackoverflow there is a script for doing that. I found it here using the search: [select file with the largest number of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891074/select-file-with-the-largest-number-of-lines).

Do you want someone to do the job for you, as there are plenty of sites that allow you to advertise for a contract programmer! Have a go at calling one batch file from the other and then come back with more questions.